# Browser downloads JSON result instead of passing back to script

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I have written a MVC3 application in which I use [Valums fileuploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). When a user uploads a file, the server passes back a JSON object indicating success/failure and possibly an error message. Some users are reporting that their browser asks them for action as if downloading a file (save/open), instead of passing the JSON to the javascript.

I'm using the uploader as distributed, and my C# controller returns a JSONResult like this

```
return JSON(new { success = true }, "application/json");
```

Or if something goes wrong

```
return JSON(new { success = false, error = exception.Message });
```

I have been unable to reproduce this, and have gotten reports from users of both IE9 and Chrome. Has anyone had this happen, and what did you do to solve it? Or where should I start troubleshooting?

**EDIT:**
The file uploader will run this on the `onComplete` event:

```
function(id, filename, responseJson) {
  if(responseJson.success != true) {
    alert("An error occurred: " + responseJson.error);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: can you show your javascript json parsing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that IE does not handle the `application/json` content type. Setting it to `text/html` makes it work, although it is quite awful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Actually, the request is not made using GET at all, but POST. And had it been AllowGet that was missing, the Controller would have thrown an error. In this case, some browsers treat the JSON returned as a file for download, which is not what I want.